# does leak sanitizer guarantee absence of memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

If I compile a c++ program using the `-fsanitize=leak` flag, does this guarantee absence of memory leaks at runtime?

Or where are some more stronger leak check tool(except valgrind)?

Comment: To quote the very popular Russian book, "Only insurance policy can give one an absolute guarantee".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

There is no guarantee the sanitizer will detect every possible leak. Nor is there a guarantee the compiler will warn about all leaks. Nor is it guaranteed that Valgrind will spot all leaks.

The tools try their best in different ways but they all have limitations (and bugs).

For example;

The compiler can only warn about leaks it can detect by analyzing your source code (and it also has an upper bound on how much time it can reasonably spend on that).

The sanitizer can only detect bugs it was written to test for - and then, it will only detect them in code you actually execute. So if a specific run of your application only exercises 50 percent of the code and the leak is in the other half it is not going to see it.

Likewise, Valgrind can only detect leaks it was designed to detect and it doesn't have access to the source, nor the benefit of compiler instrumentation and it can also only see leaks in code that actually runs.

So no. The tools not flagging any leaks does not prove the absence of leaks. That would require formal proof of correctness of not just your code but also everything it depends on (like the standard library for example) and this is not a solved problem for real-world programs.

Your best bet is to run a number of different tools and fix what they find and try to write your code carefully and deliberately and *know what you are doing*.

Comment: One kind of leak that is difficult (maybe impossible) to detect is self-referential loops.

Answer (score 1):

> ... does this guarantee absence of memory leaks at runtime?

Well, `-fsanitize` might call for overshooting expectations from the wording. The feature doesn't really ***sanitize*** the code from having problems with memory leaks, but helps to detect them.

---

As from the [GCC documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

> > ```
> > -fsanitize=leak
> >        Enable LeakSanitizer, a memory leak detector.  This option only
> >        matters for linking of executables and if neither
> >        -fsanitize=address nor -fsanitize=thread is used.  In that case
> >        the executable is linked against a library that overrides
> >        "malloc" and other allocator functions.  See
> >        <https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer >
> >        for more details.  The run-time behavior can be influenced using
> >        the LSAN_OPTIONS environment variable.
> > ```